# Any idea why/where my Android app would request access to photos when the device is set to French?

Tags: android, french

When my Android app is installed on a device set to French, it request access to photos and contacts. The main app does not need or request these. Is there somewhere that I need to change a setting to not request for any language?

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: What's in your manifest in regards to permissions? Also what version are talking about and at what point do you get asked for these permissions?

Comment: added to body so others can see as well

Comment: @NikosHidalgo, not sure if you saw my update. Any idea what could be causing the problem?

Comment: `READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is going to create a message referencing photos, when on an EN-US device. Are we sure this isn't just a translation issue? What is the exact French text?

Comment: It seems to be getting skipped on EN-US devices for some reason. On FR device, the message is: "Autoriser ------ a` acce`-der a` des photos, a` des contenus multime`dias et a` des fichiers sur votre appareil?" anything with a ` after it is accented in the message.

Comment: Well, if you paste that into Google translate, you get pretty much the exact same text for those permissions that I mentioned, in English. It does not mention contacts. I think it's fine. That is, this is design behavior, and there's not a thing you can do to change it. It's probably not showing up on the EN-US device b/c it's an older API level, or because the permission is already granted.

Comment: It sounds right. Although someone who has a french locale could help us further. Or you could actually test it by introducing the camera and contacts permissions and see if there's a different text for them.